# RabbitMQ - Shutdown epmd.exe along with service

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, daemon, epmd

Does anyone knows how to setup RabbitMQ so that epmd.exe is shutdown along with the RabbitMQ service?

This post seems to indicate it is not possible: [Is there a way to stop Erlang servers from automatically starting epmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324786/is-there-a-way-to-stop-erlang-servers-from-automatically-starting-epmd)

Otherwise said, there's probably a mecanism somewhere that starts it with the -daemon switch and I'd like to get rid of it.